# Не компилируется тест, с использованием Dagger 2 и Robolectric

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, mockito

Я написал некоторый тест, но `Dagger2` выдает ошибки, наподобие этих:

> Error:(83, 90) error: incompatible types:
>   MembersInjector cannot be converted to
>   Provider
>
> Error:(92, 70) error: method create in class
>   ArtistAdapter_MembersInjector cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Provider found: MembersInjector,Provider
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Я написал тестовые модули с использованием Mockito

PresenterTestModule

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Model provideModel() {
    return mock(Model.class);
}

@Provides
CompositeSubscription provideCompositeSubscription() {
    return new CompositeSubscription();
}
```

ModelTestModule

```
private TestUtils testUtils;

public ModelTestModule() {
    testUtils = new TestUtils();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiInterface provideApiInterface() {
    return mock(ApiInterface.class);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(Const.UI_THREAD)
Scheduler provideSchedulerUI() {
    return Schedulers.immediate();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(Const.IO_THREAD)
Scheduler provideSchedulerIO() {
    return Schedulers.immediate();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
List<Artist> provideArtistList() {
    Artist[] artists = testUtils.getGson().fromJson(testUtils.readString("raw/test.json"), Artist[].class);
    return Arrays.asList(artists);
}
```

...

TestAppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ModelTestModule.class, PresenterTestModule.class, ViewTestModule.class, AppTestModule.class, UtilsTestModule.class, PicassoTestModule.class})
public interface TestComponent extends AppComponent {
    void inject(ArtistListPresenterTest presenterTest);
    void inject(ModelImplTest modelImplTest);
}
```

Не понятно, почему не компилируется тест, в качестве примера использовался [этот репозиторий](https://github.com/andrey7mel/android-step-by-step/tree/Step_4_Unit_tests/app/src/test/java/com/andrey7mel/stepbystep), но что то пошло не так